# Replaced 2 prong with gfci--power--but not working

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I recently switched out a two prong outlet with a gfci outlet, but when the power is turned on, the volt meter reads current exists but the outlet doesn't work. I've double checked the wiring and it's correct. I also used pig tails due to the old wire being so short. How can I find what's wrong?

Update: thank you all for your responses! I double checked the wiring of the gfci outlet and it was correct.  I did not install any wires into the load screws. The voltage meter didn't indicate any power coming through the outlet. I ended up checking all of the wires in the circuit and the culprit ended up being a porcelain light fixture that was wired improperly and thus stopping the circuit from completing. I pigtailed all the connections and once that was reinstalled the right way, my outlet worked!

Comment: Does the voltmeter indicate that voltage is present at the receptacle sockets?  What do you mean by "outlet doesn't work"?

Comment: Did you hook anything to the "LOAD" terminals of the GFCI?  (the ones covered with the tape that says "do not mess with unless you know what you are doing")?

Comment: I agree with Harper I think you wired the receptacle to the "load" terminals instead of the "line" terminals. Please, re-check your wiring.

Comment: Post your update as an answer and I'll give you a +1 for it :)